# Cannot get POST data from Django request.POST

Tags: python, django, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to verify that the required data was included in a POST request. I have a `django` backend and a `vue3` frontend.

Here is my django view:

```
views.py

# Sign user in and issue token
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def login(request: HttpRequest):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check that required fields were send with POST
        print(request.body)
        if {'username', 'password'} >= set(request.POST):  # <- evaluates as False
            print('missing required fields. INCLUDED: ' + str(request.POST))
            return JsonResponse(
                data={'message': 'Please provide all required fields.'},
                content_type='application/json',
                status=400)
        # check that username exists and password matches
        if (User.objects.filter(username=request.POST['username']).count() >
                0):
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
            if user.password == request.POST['password']:
                # Delete previously issued tokens
                Token.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).delete()
                token = Token(user_id=user.id)
                token.save()
                return JsonResponse(data={'userToken': token.to_json()},
                                    content_type='application/json',
                                    status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(
                data={'message': 'Incorrect username or password.'},
                content_type='application/json',
                status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=['POST'])
```

And my axios request

```
Login.vue

axios
  .post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/login', {
    'username': form.get('username'),
    'password': form.get('password'),
  }, {
    validateStatus: (status) => {
      return status !== 500
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    if (response.data.success) {
      // Commit token value to store
      store.commit('setToken', response.data.token)
 
      // Request user data ...

    } else {
      alert.message = response.data.message
      alert.type = 'error'
      document.querySelector('#alert')?.scrollIntoView()
    }
  })
```

I can see that `username` and `password` are set in `request.body` but not `request.POST` as shown in the django log.

```
December 01, 2021 - 17:40:29
Django version 3.2.9, using settings 'webserver.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
b'{"username":"site.admin","password":"password"}'
missing required fields. INCLUDED: <QueryDict: {}>
Bad Request: /api/users/login
[01/Dec/2021 17:40:30] "POST /api/users/login HTTP/1.1" 400 50
/Users/colby/Projects/emotions/backend/webserver/users/views.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

### Edit

Here are the headers set from the axios request

```
{
  'Content-Length': '47',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Host': 'localhost:8000',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
  'Accept': 'application/json,
   text/plain, */*',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
  'Dnt': '1',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Referer': 'http://localhost:8080/',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
  'Sec-Gpc': '1'
}
```

### Edit 2

I was able to correct this issue by explicitly setting the Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data`.

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/login', formData, 
  {
     validateStatus: (status) => {
     return status !== 500
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }
).then(...)
```

I also had to adjust the if statement in the django view to

```
if 'username' not in request.POST or 'password' not in request.POST:
  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect Axios is setting automatically  a `content-type: application/json` header which means that the request body doesn't contain HTTP POST parameters that can be understood by Django.

You can verify this by printing `request.headers`, and, if this is indeed the issue, solve it by either:

1. Parsing the request body from JSON:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(response.body.decode())
if {'username', 'password'} >= set(data):  # etc.
```

2. Send the data as form data client-side:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", form.get("username"))
formData.append("password", form.get("password"))
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/login',
    formData,
    {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
  })
```

I'd personally recommand solution 1 because I find it less verbose and easier to maintain, but that mostly depends on your preferences and requirements :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I edited the post with the request headers. You're correct about the content-type header being added. When I tried with solution 1 and passed the `FormData`, I am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: I think I made a mistake, it should me `formData.append` and not `formData.set`, can you try that?

Comment: I was able to correct the issue by explicitly setting the Content Type header and changing the `if` statement to: `if 'username' not in request.POST or 'password' not in request.POST:`. I am going to accept your answer and post the finalized code in the original post.